# Issues in parsing JSON file

Tags: jquery, json

There was an example of reading jsonp request in jquery given in stackoverflow. This below code works fine.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   var url =  "http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline/codinghorror.json";
   $.getJSON(url + "?callback=?", null, function(tweets) {
    for(i in tweets) {
        tweet = tweets[i];
        $("#tweet-list").append(tweet.text + "<hr />");
    }
   });
});
```

I uploaded the json file into a temp webserver with url being http://cruzer.net76.net/twitter.json

But my json doesn't seemed to get parsed and the browser shows no errors/warnings.

Any help..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code as-is works: http://jsfiddle.net/vWRAw/

The json being returned from your temp-webserver however is JSON and not JSONP. If you want to request it as JSON, remove the `?callback=?` however that would mean your temp webserver would need to be on the same domain as the page making the request.

Comment: thanks for reply kevin..but i would want the request to be in jsonp format and not json .. it's basically the same file i've uploaded and i want to do the same operation as done with codinghorror.json.

Comment: Then you can't do it with a flat .json file. you need a server-side language to interpret the ?callback parameter and return jsonp accordingly.

Comment: sorry for my ignorance but how come .. http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline/codinghorror.json works since even this is a flat file

Comment: Because it probably isn't a flat file. It just appears to be.

Comment: A flat file wouldn't be able to take `?callback=foo` and wrap the json file with `foo(jsonhere)`